# Share data between providers

Tags: flutter, dart

It is possible to share data between providers?

This models for example:

```
class model1 with ChangeNotifier {
int num =1;
int num1 = 2;
}

class model2 with ChangeNotifier {
int func(num, num1) {
return num + num1
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use one of the following methods:

- Add a public, static member to the Provider you'd like the data associated with(will be accessible from both by using CLASS_NAME.STATIC_PROPERTY_NAME)
- Pass an instance of one of the Providers to the other one's cto'r(accessible by using INSTANCE.PROPERTY)